# How to implement same Interface method from different Interfaces - Retrofit and Twitter

Tags: java, android, twitter, retrofit2

My custom class is over-riding method from Retrofit, However in the same class, I am using Twitter, which contains a method with same definition.

I am getting warning

```
'failure(RetrofitError error)' cannot overriden 'failure(RetrofitError error)' in 'com.twitter.sdk.android.Callback' overriden method is final

@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error)
```

Same warning also here.

```
App.getRestClient().getWeatherService().getWeather("s", new Callback<ApiResponse>()
            {
                @Override
                public void success(ApiResponse apiResponse, Response response)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

So, How can I get rid of this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If a type **implements two interfaces**, and each interface define a method that has **identical signature**, then in effect there is only one method, and they are not distinguishable. If, say, the two methods have conflicting return types, then it will be a compilation error. This is the general rule of inheritance, method overriding, hiding, and declarations, and applies also to possible conflicts not only between 2 inherited interface methods, but also an interface and a super class method, or even just conflicts due to type erasure of generics.

You can inherit methods that are `@Override-equivalent`, subject to the usual requirements of method overriding and hiding. Since they ARE `@Override-equivalent`, effectively there is only one method to implement, and thus there's nothing to distinguish/select from.

The compiler does not have to identify which method is for which interface, because once they are determined to be `@Override`-equivalent, they're the same method.

Resolving potential incompatibilities may be a tricky task, but that's another issue altogether.

**To resolve the problem implement the interface anonymous**

```
public class YourClass implements RetroFitIntterface{

TwitterInterface myInterface = new TwitterInterface(){

/* Overrided method from interface */
@override
public void method1(){

}

};

/* Overrided method from superclass*/
@override
public void method1(){

}

}
```

Comment: What is answer to resolve. Both are not my own methods, one by Retrofit library, while other by Twitter.

Comment: Look into my ans last line To resolve the problem implement the interface anonymous

Comment: V S I have added the way how to resolve the issue, Please look into my ans

Comment: well, I will see, for now I am leaving retrofit, going for Async Task, Really Retrofit is bad documented.

Answer (score 0):

Believing that the message “overriden method is final” tells the truth (despite the spelling error), you cannot override. Nor do you have to — since the message is final in a superclass, it is already implemented.

Whether this gives you what you need, is a whole different story, as @Maheshwar already said.

Comment: I know this basic definition, well I think I can't get answer on stack for this question. Thanks.

Comment: Since this answer didn’t solve your problem, I suggest you implement the two different interfaces in two different classes. If you want to keep them close together, you may consider one of the classes an inner class in the other. As you know, it still won’t let you override a final method, but it _will_ allow you to distinguish between the identical methods in the two interfaces.